# FCM with a route

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an order code for a pastry shop, I've already configured all my front and back end, now I just need to finish my firebase. I'm finding it difficult to pass a route to my notification, I want it so that when the user clicks on it, it go to a specific route that I define, can anyone help me with this code snippet? Code in flutter please.

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../firebase/firebase_configures.dart';
import '../token_monitor.dart';

class Application extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Application();
}

class _Application extends State<Application> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(showFlutterNotification);

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('Um novo evento onMessageOpenedApp foi publicado!');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Cloud Messaging'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TokenMonitor(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;
bool isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = false;

Future<void> setupFlutterNotifications() async {
  if (isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized) {
    return;
  }
  channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel',
    'Notificações de Alta Importância',
    description: 'Este canal é usado para notificações importantes.',
    importance: Importance.high,
  );

  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
  isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = true;
}

void showFlutterNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  if (notification != null && android != null) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channelDescription: channel.description,
          icon: 'launch_background',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
```